# Ghost (Blog) API access without logging in?

Tags: node.js, ghost-blog

So I'm trying to host a blog, and I am trying to access the Ghost API, but I can't think of a way to access this without logging into my Ghost account. Here is the code I have:

```
    var express     = require('express'),
api         = require('../api'),
apiRoutes;
apiRoutes = function (middleware) {
var router = express.Router();

// ## Posts
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/posts', api.http(api.posts.browse));
router.post('/ghost/api/v0.1/posts', api.http(api.posts.add));
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/posts/:id(\\d+)', api.http(api.posts.read));
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/posts/:slug([a-z-]+)', api.http(api.posts.read));
router.put('/ghost/api/v0.1/posts/:id', api.http(api.posts.edit));
router['delete']('/ghost/api/v0.1/posts/:id', api.http(api.posts.destroy));
// ## Settings
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/settings/', api.http(api.settings.browse));
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/settings/:key/', api.http(api.settings.read));
router.put('/ghost/api/v0.1/settings/', api.http(api.settings.edit));
// ## Users
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/users/', api.http(api.users.browse));
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/users/:id/', api.http(api.users.read));
router.put('/ghost/api/v0.1/users/:id/', api.http(api.users.edit));
// ## Tags
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/tags/', api.http(api.tags.browse));
// ## Themes
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/themes/', api.http(api.themes.browse));
router.put('/ghost/api/v0.1/themes/:name', api.http(api.themes.edit));
// ## Notifications
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/notifications/', api.http(api.notifications.browse));
router.post('/ghost/api/v0.1/notifications/', api.http(api.notifications.add));
router['delete']('/ghost/api/v0.1/notifications/:id',api.http(api.notifications.destroy));
// ## DB
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/db/', api.http(api.db.exportContent));
router.post('/ghost/api/v0.1/db/', middleware.busboy, api.http(api.db.importContent));
router['delete']('/ghost/api/v0.1/db/', api.http(api.db.deleteAllContent));
// ## Mail
router.post('/ghost/api/v0.1/mail', api.http(api.mail.send));
router.post('/ghost/api/v0.1/mail/test', api.http(api.mail.sendTest));
// #### Slugs
router.get('/ghost/api/v0.1/slugs/:type/:name', api.http(api.slugs.generate));

return router;
};

module.exports = apiRoutes;
```

What should I add to this to ensure that I don't have to log-in each time to access the API?

Answer (score 0):

Enable session middleware and set a variable to determine whether the user is logged in or not.

```
...
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser('My secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
...
```

Then in one of your controllers or custom middleware you can set a `req.session` property.

```
req.session.loggedIn = true;
```